# How to Configure PerformancePoint Unattended Service Account using Exisitng SecureStore Target Application ID using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, performancepoint, secure-store

How can you configure PerformancePoint to use an existing Target Application ID  using PowerShell?

Neither [Set-SPPerformancePointSecureDataValues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607976.aspx) or Set-[SPPerformancePointServiceApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607676.aspx) seem to have parameter to set Target Application ID for the Unattended Service Account .

I have found the properties of the PerformancePoint Service Application object that store the Unattended Account Type (DataSourceUnattendedServiceAccountType) and the Target Application (DataSourceUnattendedServiceAccountTargetApplica):

```
$SvcName="PerformancePoint Service Application"
$SPPerformancePointService=Get-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication $SvcName
$SPPerformancePointService.DataSourceUnattendedServiceAccountType
$SPPerformancePointService.DataSourceUnattendedServiceAccountTargetApplication
```

If I try

```
$SPPerformancePointService.DataSourceUnattendedServiceAccountTargetApplication='foo'
$SPPerformancePointService.Update()
```

Then I get the following error:

*Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.SPPerformancePointMonitoringServiceApplicationPublicWrapper] 
does not contain a method named 'Update'.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no "update" for that service, the setting is immediate. Your command should have been successful. You can confirm using the UI in central admin.

I just confirmed on an installation I am working through that this works.